# App crashes when scrolling thru list

Tags: ios, uitableview, crash

I've seen this problem with many others, went thru all the topics, but I can't seem to find a solution for it.

So I have a normal table view, with a cell linked to a .xib file, at first launch everything looks normal, but once I start scroll the app crashes immediately.

By enabling zombie objects I got to this error:

> 2012-05-03 16:18:13.008 coop_dev[27547:f803] *** -[ActivityTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6853990

But I'm not sure what to look for or what might go wrong:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    ItemCell *cell = (ItemCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil) 
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ItemCell" owner:nil options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    Item *item = [self.activity objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [[cell projectLabel] setText:item.project];
    [[cell descriptionLabel] setText:item.description];
    [[cell timeLabel] setText:item.time];
    [[cell timeAgoLabel] setText:item.timeAgo];
    //cell.avatar = [UIImageView item.avatar];

    cell.descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    [cell.descriptionLabel sizeToFit];

    // remove the right arrow
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    return cell;
}
```

It works fine at first launch but after that just crashes

EDIT

I re-created the problem in a new project, just a basic table with some data, once you start scrolling it crashes. Download: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/274185/TestTable.zip

Comment: Try making sure that self.activity isn't nil

Comment: I've set some breakpoints, but it seems to crashes before it reaches them

Comment: I don't think the code you posted is relevant to your problems. Post the code instantiating the ActivityTableViewController, please.

Comment: I used interface builder to attach the controller to a table view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `FirstViewController.xib`, remove the `UITableViewController`, but leave the `UITableView`. The crash happens because the `File's Owner` is already set as class `FirstViewController` in the `Identity Inspector` and it's like you have a second `UITableViewController`. Make sure also that the `UITableView` is hooked to the view outlet of the controller.

Comment: That makes sense for that application, in then one i'm working on now the structure is a little different: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/274185/coop_dev.zip

Comment: The problem is the same in your ActivityViewController.xib - delete the UITableViewController there, but leave the UITableView

Comment: But how will I control the table that way? It's now controlled by ActivityViewTableController

Comment: Yes, and in .xib the File's Owner is marked as class ActivityViewTableController, which is implemented in ActivityViewTableController.m, in your case you have a controller within the controller and that's why it crashes. Get rid of the controller in the .xib and it will work fine with the logic in ActivityViewTableController.m

Comment: The File's owner is marked as class ActivityViewController, which doesn't do anything, that's why I'm a little confused about this

Comment: Create a new UITableViewController with .xib clicked and see the configuration Xcode generates for you.

Comment: I understand that, but how can I use that TableViewController in my other view then?
I solver it now by removing the ActivityViewController and replacing it with the TableViewController, since the first one wasn't doing anything

Comment: You can reuse it everywhere just initializing it, as you have done in the app delegate and the either add the controller.view as a subview of a view or pass the controller to a navigation controller or tabbar controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I think I understand it now, it's all a little new to me.

Answer (score 0):

You are dequeueing code is a bit off... try mine:

```
     UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
cell = nil;
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:@"cell"]
            autorelease];


    cell.imageView.image = nil;
    cell.textLabel.text = nil;

}
```

Comment: The OP wants a cell from a NIB, not to create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `ItemCell` class' `dealloc` method, you're probably overreleasing something.

Comment: I only have [super dealloc]; in it, this is my ItemCell as a reference: http://pastebin.com/2J37Gjx2